# Neo4j: enforce node uniqueness, one-to-one match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Compared to what I am doing below, is there a more optimal way to ensure a one-to-one relationship between the nodes in the query graph and the nodes in the matches that are obtained?

For example, suppose I want to find paths of length 4 consisting of unique nodes. I could have a query like:

```
MATCH (n2)--(n1)--(n0)--(n3)--(n4)
return n0,n1,n2,n3,n4
```

However, this does not ensure the matched nodes are distinct. For instance, n2 and n4 are allowed to match (which would give me a cycle). I can add a where clause "where not(n2=n4)", but other nodes can match too. It seems like I will need to add this clause for all pairs of nodes that I want to be unique, which is annoying on large subgraphs.

Is there a better way to ensure a one-to-one relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Use the path variable and verify the uniqueness of the nodes in the path:

```
MATCH p = (n1)--(n2)--(n3)--(n4)--(n5)
      // Enumerate all nodes in the path
WHERE ALL(n1 IN nodes(p) WHERE
        // Each node must occur only once
        size([n2 IN nodes(p) WHERE n1 = n2]) = 1
      )
return n1, n2, n3, n4, n5
```

Or you can use the function to check for duplicates in the list from the [`APOC library`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#collection-list-functions):

```
MATCH p = (n1)--(n2)--(n3)--(n4)--(n5)
WHERE apoc.coll.containsDuplicates(nodes(p)) = FALSE
return n1, n2, n3, n4, n5
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess my post was a little misleading, because I am not really focused on paths specifically. This may be the best we can do though, the second solution looks clean, for paths.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, depending on the actual query, you may be able to make use of the path expander procs in APOC Procedures, as there's a way to specify that you only want paths where nodes cannot repeat within each path.

For example:

```
MATCH (n)
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(n, {minLevel:4, maxLevel:4, uniqueness:'NODE_PATH'}) YIELD path
WITH nodes(path) as nodes
RETURN nodes[0] as n1, nodes[1] as n2, nodes[2] as n3, nodes[3] as n4, nodes[4] as n5
```

You would of course want to use labels for the actual query at the least, as this is going to attempt the expansion on every node in your database otherwise.